# Wordpress: Include custom_fields (Book author) in search results

Tags: wordpress

I am using TwentyEleven as my base theme which I have skinned.
In my Content.php file, the search results looks something like this

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I am trying to pull the "Author" Meta key/value pairs to return in my search results along with the Post Title and Post Content like so:

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>
        <?php get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), _wpsc_author, true); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Note the line:

```
<?php get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), _wpsc_author, true); ?>
```

Yet, this returns nothing?

I have read a fair amount on the topic of the_meta(), get_post_custom() etc, but nothing I am trying seems to have worked.

Would appreciate some insight?

**EDIT:** 
Apologies, I wasn't too clear about the "Author" part.
Author is a custom field in the post_meta table along with "book type", book condition" published year" etc. It is not the Post Author.

Thanks

Comment: Also try print_r( get_post_custom() ); We're wanting to see if _wpsc_author is actually in your meta. Also.. this code looks like it's in the loop, we're in the loop right?

Comment: It seems like you're only pulling the author meta on non-search pages. That's a bit confusing as to whether that's exactly what you want, since you say that you want to display that information in the search results. Consider moving the `<?php echo (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), _wpsc_author, true)); ?>` part after `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing just add echo before the function it will display the result and the last argument of the function will give you an array if it is set to false and a string if it set to true so change it according to your requirement

Comment: You mean like this <?php echo (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), _wpsc_author, true)); ?> Abhimanue? If I do that, it still returns nothing.

Comment: `<?php 
$post_id = $post->ID;
$key = $prefix.'City_Railway_Station';
$meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
echo $meta_values;
?>`
this is how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `the_author_meta();` ?

You can use it like: `the_author_meta('user_email')`

Please note this function only works inside the loop... but there are ways around it, but they're gross.

available keys:

```
user_login
user_pass
user_nicename
user_email
user_url
user_registered
user_activation_key
user_status
display_name
nickname
first_name
last_name
description
jabber
aim
yim
user_level
user_firstname
user_lastname
user_description
rich_editing
comment_shortcuts
admin_color
plugins_per_page
plugins_last_view
ID
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, I've added an EDIT and cleaned up my question a little. I wasn't too clear about "Author" in my initail post. Thanks for the tip though, I will use it at some point no doubt

Comment: Woops misread you there. That looks like it should work, but try two things for me; check to see if it works with _wpsc_author in quotes '_wpsc_author', and that get_the_ID() is returning the correct ID